# Code Review Question about disposing

Tags: spweb, dispose

Don't `web.Dispose()` dispose parent `SPSite` object?

Is it Ok if I do this in web part?

```
{              
    SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;

    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(s))
    {
         // ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you written is Ok.

`using` statement will dispose the `SPWeb` object you have instantiated.

Parent Site - This object is not initiantiated by you, you are using `SPSite` that belongs to `SPContext`.

`SPContext` objects are managed by the SharePoint framework and should not be explicitly disposed in your code. This is true also for the `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects returned by `SPContext.Site`, `SPContext.Current.Site`, `SPContext.Web`, and `SPContext.Current.Web`.

Comment: Thank for response! I asked becouse was afraid if Web dispose() could implicitly call site dispose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's acceptable to do what you have done. It's also ok to pass that web object to other functions.

See a detailed article on this subject from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx#sharepointobjmodel_otherobjectsthatrequire-disposal).